# Visual Studio Code not caching git password on Linux

Tags: linux, git, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code (latest version) is not caching git password on Linux and pops up an annoying alert window (that blocks the whole UI). I tried this command unsuccessfully:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: How are you trying to store & use the cached password?

Comment: When using git in VS Code (e.g pulling or pushing) the application opens a window asking for the git password. I imagine running the above command line above would cache the password that I enter either from the command line or from VS Code...

Answer (score 2):

If the cache credential helper is not working, try, as [in this tweet](https://twitter.com/code/status/658752767788363776)

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

It is a more basic way of caching credentials though (not in memory but in file)

Answer (score 1):

The annoying part is that this window pops up every 5 minutes or so. You can disable the Git `autofetch` option using the `User Settings`.

Go to `File > Preferences > User Settings`. 2 different pages should appear in the editor: `Default Settings` and `settings.json`.
In the JSON file, simply type: `"git.autofetch": false`.

Save and you will not be annoyed by this pop-up anymore.
However, you would still need to type in your credentials when pushing/pulling.